# how to make a UDF in sql for determining month of year?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I want to make a user defined function for calculating the month number from date. 
But the problem is that I have the months numbered as 1, 2, 3 ... and each month is of 26 days, that makes a total of 13 months in the year, rather than 12

any useful help?

Comment: You developed your own calendaring system? Might I ask why?

Comment: JUst out curiosity what did you name the 13th month?

Comment: Your years have 338 days in them?

Comment: hey James, it is the client's requirement :)

HLGEM, I had mentioned it earlier that I haven't given them any names, months are just numbered as 1, 2, 3 etc.

adrift, sorry the days are 27 for each month.

Comment: lamak : I have created a function for the calculation of leap year, it works perfectly fine as 27 days are for the rest of the months, february is treated as a special case (normal 28 days n 29 for leap year)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to ask you why you'd want to do this.  But here we go:

```
select convert(int, (datepart(Dayofyear, @date)-1)/26.0)+1
```

Comment: it is working in some cases, but not all.
can you please elaborate the statement so that I may be able to modify it by myself?

Comment: @MuhammadHaadi Can you show an example of cases that don't work as expected?

Comment: the dates at the margin of a month, it mixes it up with the next month number e.g. if the 4th month is ending at 04/15/2011 (mm/dd/yyyy) and the next month (5th month) starts at 04/16/2011, it tells both as the 4th month.

Comment: What have you done on your own?  That is, what parts do you and don't you understand?  Show some effort and you'll be more likely to be helped.